# jQuery - Functions for Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been learning jQuery over the past few weeks. I decided to set myself tasks in order to learn in a more "fun" way. So I decided to make my own carousel - I know there are plenty of carousels out there and I'm certain they're much better than mine, but making my own is helping me understand how things work :)

**Here's what I have so far:** http://jsfiddle.net/12jjno2c/

There are few things I'm trying to accomplish but I don't seem to be getting very far with them, so any assistance would be massively appreciated :)

1. If the first item is left 0px I want the left arrow button to be disabled.

   - I've tried doing this with `event.preventDefault();` and `return false,` but I'm either doing it wrong or it's not working.
2. When the final item is scrolled to, I want it the next button to slide back to the first item. (left: 0px)

   - I'm not sure how to do this - But I have a variable finding the number of items in the carousel. So I think it would be something like after variable number of clicks slide back to 0px?
3. When I click quickly, it throws my slides out of sync, so you end up with half items showing at the ends sometimes.

   - I'm not sure how I'd do this either, maybe set a 1 click per a set amount of time? I've never heard of this though, so I might be clutching at straws!
4. Finally, Is there any way of making the carousel infinite? For example, after you get to the 10th item, the 1st one comes back around and it cycles through infinitely? This sort of contradicts my first 2 questions. But I'd like to know how to do both.

That was a lot to take in sorry!! Any help with parts or all of this would be phenomenal! Thank you kindly for you time! :)

Answer (score 0):

I added some conditions. One of them on Next button click:

```
// end of items
if ($('.item').last().position().left ==
    $('#carousel').width() - carouselItemWidth)
    return false;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/12jjno2c/1/

To solve point no. 4, you can animate items container left position to 0px.